# Ubuntu version for laravel

Tags: laravel, ubuntu-16.04

Does Ubuntu 16.04 is the best version to use for Laravel? , There was a time that I was searching for best server for laravel and I across several sites that telling they are using Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

It is not any differences for laravel. But for server I personally prefer Debian.

Comment: Thanks I will look about it.

Answer (score 0):

It's an LTS so thats good because you'll get support until April 2021. You'll need to update your server to PHP 7.1 though.

Ubuntu 17.10 support PHP 7.1 so thats nice. But you'll get security updates and stuff until July 2018.

I'm using 16.04 but if you have a time until 26 of april, I'd wait for the 18.04 LTS stable release

Comment: can you give me a reference site where you have read it? I just want to know more about it if it is okay with you, thank you :)

Comment: [https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseSchedule]

[https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-apache-mariadb-php7-1-ubuntu-17-10]

[https://itsfoss.com/ubuntu-18-04-release-features/]